# How to modify global variables from config.py, but retain default values in package namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

In my package, I have low level utility functions (`utility.py`), and higher level functions that call the utility functions (`main.py`). Default arguments (strings and scalars) for the utility functions are stored in `config.py`.

```
\my_module
    main.py
        fun1()
    utils.py
        fun2()
    config.py
        setting="A"
```

Now I want to allow users to modify these settings by providing optional kwargs locally to the utility functions, or to the high-level functions. The tricky thing is that fun1 cannot pass on any arguments to fun2 directly, for reasons that don't matter here, so it needs to happen through a global scheme.

```
# utils.py
import config

def fun2(..., **kwargs):
    setting = kwargs.get("setting", config.setting)

# main.py
import config

def fun1(..., **kwargs):
    config.setting = kwargs.get("setting")    

    ## fun 2 gets called indirectly, without the possibility to pass on "setting" directly
```

So, this is fine: `fun2(settings="B")`, but when I do this `fun1(settings="B")`, I have the problem that `config.setting` gets overwritten in the package namespace (not in the actual file though):

```
> print(my_module.config.setting)
> "B"
```

I would like the package namespace (`my_module.config.setting`) to retain the default value ("A") - what is a general and pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A lot about this design gives me a pause, but you can do something like this:

```
class Config:
    setting = "foo"
```

Then, in whatever module you need it, use:

```
from config import Config

config = Config()
```

And maybe consider naming the module something like `configuration.py`

Comment: I'll give this a shot. care to elaborate what exactly is problematic with "this" design - i.e., what design exactly?

Comment: @mluerig relying on mutable global state is a classic antipattern.

Comment: @mluerig wait, you want to be able to modify `config` in `main.py`, but have it affect `config` in `utils.py`?

Comment: mhh ok but to avoid that it would require significant amounts of boilerplate, which I am trying to reduce in my package. and `setting` is really only used for fun2, so a bit of a tradeoff situation here

Comment: yes that's the goal - i.e., to control an element in fun2 from fun1, without having access to fun1 directly

Comment: @mluerig well then what I have above won't work, but the same principle can be applied, maybe just create a `config = Config()` inside `configuraiton.py`, then you can modify that, and all the default values remain in the class `Config`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237217/discussion-between-mluerig-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).